# why can't I compile with the Integer/System.readInt() function

Tags: java

```
public void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fylki = System.readInt(args[0]);
        while(!StdIn.isEmpty()){
            StdOut.print("Number of pairs in array: " + checkingPairs(fylki));
        }
    }
```

I am wondering what I'm doing incorrect here. I have imported the java.lang.*; and both the StdIn; and StdOut;. I first tried to have

```
public void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fylki = Integer.readInt(args[0]);
        while(!StdIn.isEmpty()){
            StdOut.print("Number of pairs in array: " + checkingPairs(fylki));
        }
    }
```

but I got the same error for both

```
pairs.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        int[] fylki = System.readInt(args[0]);
                            ^
  symbol:   method readInt(String)
  location: class System
```

Comment: I've never heard of `System.readInt` or `Integer.readInt` - and neither has your compiler.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` is the method you're looking for - but `StdIn` and `StdOut` are also not part of the Java standard library. Are you using a custom library (perhaps provided by a teacher, or an online learning environment) where these classes are defined?

Answer (score 0):

## What you did and where the problems are

The class `System` (or `Integer`) doesn't have a method `readInt()`.

You can use `Integer.parseInt()` if you want an `int` instead.

Also, there is no class `Stdin`(as long as you haven't created it by yourself), but you could use `System.in`.

But there isn't a method `isEmpty()` in `System.out`(or `InputStream`, whatever you want). However, you could read one byte and check if the return value is 0(don't forget that this byte will be missing later).

By the way, `java.lang.*` is imported by default. You don't have to import it manually.

I think you mixed something up with other programming languages.

Here are a few things you could mean(as you pointed out in the comments, you want to get the ints from `stdin`):

## get `int[]` from first argument (with delimitor)

If you want to split it using some String, you can use it in combination with Streams(`seq` is the delimitor):

```
int[] fylki=Stream.of(args[0].split(seq)).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(int[]::new);
```

This splits the first argument(in java `args[0]` is not the program path) by the delimitor (regex) and processes it using a Stream. It maps every part of the stream to an integer using `Integer.parseInt()`. Finally, it converts it to a new array.

## get `int[]` from all arguments (1 arg =1 int)

If you want to parse all args to an int array(ints seperated by spaces), you could do this even easier:

```
int[] fylki=Stream.of(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(int[]::new);
```

This is the same but you do not split it because you already have it as array.

## read ints from `stdin` (with `Scanner`)

If you want to read ints from `stdin`(or `System.in` in java), you could use a `Scanner`.

At first, you could create a `List` to store the ints and a `Scanner` where you read the ints from.

After that, you read all the ints and store them to the `List`.

Finally, you copy the content of the `List` to the `int[]` you want and close the `Scanner`.

```
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    ints.add(scan.nextInt();
}
int[] fylki=ints.toArray(new int[0]);
scan.close();
```

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Thanks. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I think it's a learning exercise. It so, maybe it'll be a learning exercise in explaining how the stream got into the solution handed in :)

Comment: @Scratte yeah, I've added an explaination.

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant that it seems too advanced compared to the code samples we've seen on the question. I don't even think the PO knows how to use javaDoc.

Comment: I was looking for In.readInts() it seems. Thank you all for the help :)

Comment: @HelgaRun I've added that too.